# throw exception [__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate

This is my code :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"str: %@",str);

NSDictionary *dict = [str JSONValue];

NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];



NSArray *array = [[dict objectForKey:@"event"] retain];

NSLog(@"Array: %@",array);



for (NSDictionary *tempdict in array)
{


    NSDate *d = [fmt dateFromString:[tempdict objectForKey:@"eve_date"]];
    NSLog(@"Date %@",d);
    NSLog(@"Date of event %@",[tempdict objectForKey:@"eve_date"]);

    NSDate *t =[tempdict objectForKey:@"eve_date"];
            NSLog(@"Date of t %@",t);
    NSLog(@"This is title_event %@",[tempdict objectForKey:@"title"]);
    NSLog (@"Time of event %@", [tempdict objectForKey:@"eve_time"]);
    NSLog(@"This is description %@",[tempdict objectForKey:@"description"]);

[eventPHP addObject:[Events eventsNamed:[tempdict objectForKey:@"title"] description:[tempdict objectForKey:@"description"] date:t]];}
dataReady = YES;
[callback loadedDataSource:self];}



+ (Events*)eventsNamed:(NSString *)atitle description:(NSString *)adescription date:(NSDate *)aDate {

return [[[Events alloc] initWithName:atitle description:adescription date:aDate] autorelease]; }
```

it is print all my data fine but in this line

```
    [eventPHP addObject:[Events eventsNamed:[tempdict objectForKey:@"title"] description:[tempdict objectForKey:@"description"] date:t]];
```

there is exception :

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6149cb0'

Comment: what class is eventPHP? is it an NSArray?

Comment: please post initWithName:atitle description:adescription date:aDate method on Events

Comment: Code samples should be complete and concise. Please provide a [minimal sample](http://sscce.org/). The current sample has extraneous code.

Comment: Mike K :

eventPHP it is array [ NSMutableArray ]

Dimitar

    - (id)initWithName:(NSString *)atitle description:(NSString *)adescription date:(NSDate *)aDate {
 

 if ((self = [super init])) {
  title = [atitle copy];
  description = [adescription copy];
  date = [aDate retain];
 }
 return self;}



is any problem in  initWithName ?

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the `length` message to an `NSDate` object, but `NSDate` objects do not understand the `length` message.  You did not show us the code that sends that message.

If you set a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`, Xcode will stop your app in the debugger when the exception occurs, so you can see exactly where the `length` message is sent.

Comment: ya i use it with NSLog in initWhithName in line return self there is exception